# Get ID of draggable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way in native HTML5 drag and drop to get the id of the element with the attribut `draggable="true"` ?

At first i thought it's standard that you get the id from the draggable container but actually it is always the id from the children element you start dragging on which is very annoying.

Here is an fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/chickberger/2ujhodeh/2/

I need the id from the div ('correctid') instead of the image.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a reference to that element by accessing the [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of the `target` property on the `event` object.

In your case, `event.target` was referring to the innermost element that was being targeted.

You want the `currentTarget` property since it refers to the element that the event listener is attached to (which would be the element with the `ondragstart` attribute).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/yksh00jj/)

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.currentTarget.id);
    alert(ev.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works flawless! Wonder why i never came across this property in all these articles i was reading about drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ev.target' is an image. You can fix this by using the parentNode:

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.parentNode.id);
    alert(ev.target.parentNode.id);
}
```