# How to control the source TD styling in a drag and drop JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, drag-and-drop

In a drag and drop cycle you can control all kind of styling of the 'dragged element' and at ondrop, but is it also possible to control styling of the source?

In my case I drag an ancher element from one TD to another TD. In the function drop(event) I can style the target TD in anyway I want. See code below.

```
// The actual drop event
function drop(event) {
    // Prevent the default action for a drop (activate link)
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the ID from the dragged item
    var iRecordID = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    // Get the ID from the dropzone
    var sXeduledata = event.target.id;            
    // Put the dragged element in the dropzone
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(iRecordID));
    // Change the dropzone styling
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    event.target.style.border = ""; 
    event.target.style.textAlign = "center";        
    // Connect to a php file and saving the new data
    $.post('dnd-update.php', 
    {sXeduleData:sXeduledata,iRecordNumber:iRecordID});        
}
```

But I need to style and prepare the 'source' TD for re-use as a 'dropzone'. To be more precize a green source need to become a white target.
How do I accomplish that?

PHP source code:

```
protected function showXeduleItemContent($p_aXeduleItem){
   echo("<td class='text-center h5 back_green' class='droptarget' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' id='".$sDay.":".$iRE.":".$aClassroomRecord[0]."'>");
   echo("<a href='foo.php' draggable='true' id='".$p_aXeduleItem[0]."'>".$aLessonName[0][2]."</a></td>");
}
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP. Include only the HTML output in future and don't tag as PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get ID of draggable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446592/get-id-of-draggable-element)

Comment: Also you should not be using HTML attributes to add event listeners; it's very 1998. You have the jQuery library installed, you may as well use it to set up event listeners and updates styles as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Milken32. He put me on the right track. 
After some more diging about "parentNode" I found the answer I needed.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp

The answer is to add 'event.target.parentNode.style' to the 'dragstart' event.

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    // The event.dataTransfer.setData() method saves the data type for later use in the script
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);    
    // Styling of the source better know as parent
    event.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "white";        
});
```